# Accessing csv-file via a path saved in another csv-file

Tags: vba, excel

I want to combine two csv into one new csv file via a vba macro but have problems accessing the values of the two files.
I can open the first file with Workbooks.Open() but I can not access any of its values by File1.ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1) or File1.ActiveSheet.Range(1,1) etc.
The catch is, that I have to open the second file through a path that is contained in the first file.

The Files look like this:

File1

[image: File1]

File2

[image: File2]

For every ID in File1 there is one File2 with about ~30000-60000 entrys that need to be mapped together.

My Idea was to copy File2 into the new File and than add the ID for every row.
I can not just change the File2 and ad the ID there since I have no writting rights to the Folder they are in.

The Struktur the Files are in at the Moment:

WorkingDir
 | 
|___File1 
|___Macro 
|___allFile2 
.........|__File2_1 
.........|__File2_2

Is there a better approach to this?
I am new to vba programming and have almost no practise in it i would be really greatful if someone can help me or has some literatur that could help.

Comment: Are you getting an error when you try to access the values with `File1.ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create another worksheet that can be used a medium for importation. What you would be doing is creating a macro that enables you to select another file from a open file window and then another macro that will copy and paste the desired data range. If you want to create a macro that integrates it into the other file you could do that as well.

**Here is an example of how you might structure the File Select code:**

```
    Sub GetFile()
'Dim the variables
Dim FileSelect As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
'on error statement
On Error GoTo errHandler:
'hold in memory
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'locate the file path
FileSelect = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*", _
MultiSelect:=False)
'check if a file is selected
If FileSelect = False Then
MsgBox "Select the file name"
Exit Sub
End If
'send the path to the worksheet
Sheet8.Range("C4").Value = FileSelect
'open the workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileSelect)
'add the sheet names to the workbook
'close the workbook
wb.Close False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
```

**This would be an example of your importation code:**

```
Public Sub GetRange()
'Dim variables
Dim FileSelect As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Addme As Range, _
CopyData As Range, _
Bk As Range, _
Sh As Range, _
St As Range, _
Fn As Range, _
Tb As Range, _
c As Range
'on error statement
On Error GoTo errHandler:
'hold values in memory
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'check neccessary cells have values
For Each c In Sheet8.Range("C4,F4,G4,H4")
If c.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "You have left out a value that is needed in " & c.Address
Exit Sub
End If
Next c
'set the range reference variables
Set Bk = Sheet8.Range("C4") 'file path of book to import from
Set Sh = Sheet8.Range("G4") 'Worksheet to import
Set St = Sheet8.Range("G4") 'starting cell reference
Set Fn = Sheet8.Range("H4") 'finishing cell reference
'set the destination
Set Addme = Sheet8.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
'open the workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Bk)
'set the copy range
Set CopyData = Worksheets(Sh.Value).Range(St & ":" & Fn)
'copy and paste the data
CopyData.Copy
Addme.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'clear the clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False
'close the workbook
wb.Close False
'return to the interface sheet
Sheet8.Select
    End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
'error block
errHandler:
MsgBox "An Error has Occurred " & vbCrLf & "The error number is: " _
& Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & _
"Please notify the administrator"
End Sub
```

This is merely an example of how you would structure it generally. You would need to build the excel worksheet for the references needed for the variables listed in the code.

A great resource for this subject is found at this website: http://www.onlinepclearning.com/import-data-into-excel-vba/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Let me know if this is helpful!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, it actually did help me a lot and I got it up and running.
thank you!